# About catalan number's expression from wiki

Tags: algorithm, catalan

According to the wiki [catalan definition from wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), I see the expression below:
[image]

I can understand the first two expressions, but really confused about the third one. The pi symbol stands for the multiply. Does the expression mean the code below:

```
for (int i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
    sum *= (n + i)/i;
}
```

My code is below

```
public class Test {
public  int getCatalan(int n) {
    //Catalan Number = (2n)!/(n+1)!*n!
    int product = 1;
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;

    for (int i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
        product *= (n+i)/i;
    }
    return product;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();

    for (int i = 1;i < 7; i++) {
        System.out.println("when i=" + i + " its catalan number is "+ test.getCatalan(i));
    }
}
```

}

and I get the result is totally wrong

[image]

Anyone help me?

Comment: Thank you! But according to this expression, i cannot get the right answer of catalan number, for n=3 I get catalanNumber=4, but it should be 5. what's wrong with my logic? And I did not see anyone do it like this way. They all use recursion way C(n+1)= 2(2n+1)*C(n)/(n+1). @Dukeling.

Comment: Change `i < n` to `i <= n`. The pi notation includes the upper value for the iterator, not just those values strictly less than it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That's roughly what it means (assuming you initialized `sum` to 1).

But be careful with integer division. If you write `(n + i)/i` and both `n` and `i` are integers, you might find yourself with some unintended output in certain languages.

For instance, in Java, if `n = 3` and `i = 2`, `(n + i)/i = 2`, instead of `2.5`, since `int / int = int` and we can't store `2.5` in an integer.

If you cast something `double` or add a `+ 0.0` or `* 1.0` there somewhere, the result would be a `double` (`double / int = double`) and should be correct.

Also keep in mind that `sum` itself should be a `double` / `float`, not an `int` (because, `sum` can't store `2.5`, similarly to what was mentioned above). If you want the output to be an `int`, you should `Math.round` it.

```java
int n = 3;
double product = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
   product *= (0.0 + n + i)/i;
}
System.out.println(product); // 5
```

(I also changed `i < n + 1` to `i <= n` - the latter seems clearer to me, but it doesn't functionally change the code)

For more technical details, see the JLS - [Division Operator /](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) and [Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Make sure to initialize `sum` (which should probably be called `product`) to 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably safer to use longs or BigIntegers (or an equivalent in whatever language you use) to avoid floating point errors. You can just keep track of the numerator and denominator and divide at the end. (or keep reducing in between steps to reduce chance of overflow)

```
long catalan(long n) {
    long p = 1;
    long q = 1;
    for (long k = 2; k <= n; k++) {
        p *= (n + k);
        q *= k;

        // these 3 lines are optional, and just delay when overflow happens
        long gcd = gcd(p, q);
        p /= gcd; 
        q /= gcd;
    }
    return p / q;
}
```

check out a comparison here: https://coderpad.io/565957 using doubles will give you the wrong answer by the time n=30, with gcd mine's only good to 33, but you can easily swap out longs for BigIntegers to go indefinitely.